# I made a radio button on python and it automatically selects itself. How do i change this?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I want users to be able to select and deselect the radio button.
When i run my program it automatically selects itself. I want users to be able to click it on and off. How can i do this
thanks :)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Set the radiobutton to an non corresponding one. For example `form.var.set(99)`

Comment: A single Radiobutton? They normally are used in groups. Maybe you should be using a Checkbutton instead if you only want one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to set the variable assigned to the `variable` attribute of the `Radiobutton` to a value not assigned in your `Radiobutton`, like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
var.set(None)

radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Option1", variable=var, value=True)
radio.pack()

root.mainloop()
```